# c@something.se not recognized as a valid address

Tags: regex

I just realized my regular expression for email does not recognize `c@something.se` as a valid email address. But it actually is. How can I improve this on the expression?

```
\A([a-z0-9!#_%&'""=`{}~\-\+\*\?\^\|\/\$])+([a-z0-9!#_%&'""=`{}~\.\-\+\*\?\^\|\/\$])+([a-z0-9!#_%&'""=`{}~\-\+\*\?\^\|\/\$])+@{1}([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,64}\z
```

Comment: What language are you using? If PHP you could use filter_var() build in function with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.

Comment: @f.gorczynski It's c#. Sorry. I thought they all use the same language.